# How to convert BeamRecord into String in BeamSql

Tags: apache-beam

I'm converting a beamRecord into String . Below is the code snippet :

```java
PCollection<BeamRecord> output_A = apps.apply(BeamSql.query("select Outlet from PCOLLECTION"));
output_A.apply(TextIO.write().to("gs://google_bucket/output/sbc.txt"));
```

output_A is in BeamRecord format and needs to get converted into String so that it can be written to output file .

Below is the error on output_A.apply:

> The method apply(PTransform,OutputT>) in the type PCollection is not applicable for the arguments (TextIO.Write)

So my question is how to convert BeamRecord into String format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply a transform to the pipeline which converts a `BeamRecord` to a `String` before applying the `TextIO.Write` transform. There are a number of ways to do this. You can convert the `BeamRecord` to a `String` in any way you want.

Simple `toString()`.

```
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {

    // c.element() returns a BeamRecord
    c.output(c.element().toString());
}
```

Or get specific field value(s) from the `BeamRecord`.

```
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {

    // c.element() returns a BeamRecord
    c.output(c.element().getString("fieldName"));
}
```

Reference: [BeamRecord](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/values/BeamRecord.html)